# Regex to capture string with multiple optional words

Tags: regex, option-type

I'm using Overpass API's regex. Unsure which flavour it uses.

I'm wishing to capture these strings:

```
"Footpath"
"Public Footpath"
"Footpath No. 27001"
"Public Footpath No. 125"
"Footpath #424"
"Public Footpath #5"
```

This fails to return the first two options.

```
^(Public)?Footpath (No\. |#)?[0-9]
```

How do I make the 'No./#  optional?
I've tried variations on wrapping them in brackets, but to no avail eg.

```
^(Public)?Footpath ((No\. |#)?[0-9])?
```

I'm afraid I'm out of my depth.

Comment: I haven't really looked into it but it most likely fails on the first two due to the spaces. Your regex expects no space in front of "Footpath" and always a space after "Footpath".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex with multiple optional non-capturing groups:

```sh
^(?:Public )?Footpath(?: No\.)?(?: #?[0-9]+)?$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/TtkxNS/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?:Public )?`: Match `Public`  in an optional non-capturing group
- `Footpath`: Match `Footpath`
- `(?: No\.)?`: Match  `No\.` in an optional non-capturing group
- `(?: #?[0-9]+)?`: Match space followed by optional # and 1+ digits in an optional non-capturing group
- `$`: End